# OpenOffice-Calc How to set a maximum value for a column

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm trying to set the maximum number of a column to 50, so any number greater than 50 should show up as 50 in the spreadsheet. I'm not sure if using find and replace is the way to go. I can't seem to find a way to make find and replace look for numbers greater than 50.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind found an easy way to do it with an if statement. Ended up using

=IF(B1>50;50;B1)